How to use Dynatrace with Expo SDK 50/51?
I had Dynatrace properly integrated with Expo SDK 49. I did the upgrade to SDK 50 and then SDK 51 now and get the following error on my development client build (The preview and production channels seem to work fine.):
Unable to resolve "@dynatrace/react-native-plugin/jsx-dev-runtime" from "App.tsx"

I think the reason is that babel decides based on the environment if it uses jsx-runtime or jsx-dev-runtime. It seems that @dynatrace/react-native-plugin doesn't ships with jsx-dev-runtime.
Anyone got this working?
Versions I use:
"expo": "^51.0.0",
"@dynatrace/react-native-plugin": "^2.295.1",
"@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
"@babel/parser": "^7.25.3",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.3",
"babel-preset-expo": "~11.0.0",


This was fixed in the newest version of the dynatrace react-natvie-plugin:
"@dynatrace/react-native-plugin": "^2.297.2"

